# What does the red background of some toggle switches in CRJ 700/900 overhead panel mean?

Tags: cockpit, bombardier-crj

I've noticed, that some of the toggle switches (e.g. DC Switch or the four Hydraulic Pumps) have a red Background whereas others (e.g. GEN1 and GEN2) are unpainted.
[Here](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/128837) you can see what i mean.
Is there a special meaning to the red color? First i thought that systems marked with red require a running ENG or APU. But the red on the DOME Light switch obviously does not match.

Comment: Does the color change between airframes, or are red switches always used for the same switches?

Comment: @mins See ymb1's (now deleted) answer. It seems consistent at least since the 200 variant.

Comment: @Bianfable: Precisely I have a doubt on the fact they are the same, e.g. on [this comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4yUb.jpg) from two links provided in the answer this is not obvious the same switches are used for A/C fan or windshield anti-ice. In addition on the LH picture A/C fan is bistate and red while on the RH it seems to be tristate and uncolored, which is the contrary of the Hydraulic panel scheme.

Answer (score 12):

There isn't actually any particular meaning to those colours. Those switches have a rubber boot at the base to seal out moisture and outside dust, etc, and the rubber happens to be red because that's what the supplier used. Lever Lock switches like the Gen switches don't have a visible boot (the seal is internal) and a couple of the other ones have no boots or boots that are grey rubber because that happens to be what that particular switch came with.

Comment: I'd really like to upvote this, but my gut says there is _always_ a meaning behind the choices of colors used in control panels.

Comment: Me too, I always feel that!

Comment: I was on the program for 25+ years and I can tell you the colour of the rubber used in the dust boot has no relationship to anything.

Comment: Well, there you go.

Comment: @JohnK   Even then, the colour still means something - the supplier/manufacturer of the switches isn't going to change their colour in the middle of a batch...

Comment: They'll just follow the spec for the switch, which might say something like "Boot material of silicone rubber, colour red, to MIL-S-XXXXXXX".  As to why red, or black, or grey, if there are any, the reasons are lost to the mists of time...

Comment: I've seen switches like these for years in many applications, they're not just in airplanes.  Red for whatever reason seems to be the most common color for the rubber.  Maybe because it's easier to see if the seal is damaged and needs replacing than with a black seal?  Being rubber, they do tend to dry up and crack over time.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Glass jar rubber seals are red. Rubber bands are (used to be at least) red. The seals on my blender are red. Red just seems to be the most common color for rubber in general.

Comment: I think there's a reason. That red/orange color is very commonly used to denote the material is capable of handling high temperatures, and I suspect it's used because the polymer is flame retardant. I think it's originally because it imparts the look of brick and clay, as well as being a bright color so that cracks are easily visible. Examples include bleed air ducts, firestop in buildings, welding screens, insulating gloves and mats for power lines, and silicone oven mats.

Comment: Yeah things like fire sleeve and Scat hose are that colour, but it's just a dye so you can make it any colour you want.  Some firesleeve is black.  Temperature resistance isn't an issue with these switches.